# Enum element 'default' cannot be referenced as an instance member

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I keep getting this error:

```
Enum element 'default' cannot be referenced as an instance member
```

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let list = ["École Privée"]


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
       return(list.count)
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: <#T##UITableViewCellStyle#>.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return(cell)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: let cell = UITableViewCell(style: <#T##UITableViewCellStyle#>.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

Comment: try `let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")`

Comment: That fixed it thanks!

Comment: In the simulator, I don't get "École Privée" however. Just a blank list. Any ideas?

Comment: check that, dataSource is set to your viewController and that `numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)` returns 1

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On this line of code:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: <#T##UITableViewCellStyle#>.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Exchange `<#T##UITableViewCellStyle#>.default` for `.default` so it would look like this:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

That should fix your problem.